# Javascript if statement with multiple permissible conditions

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript: The prettiest way to compare one value against multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121395/javascript-the-prettiest-way-to-compare-one-value-against-multiple-values)
>   [Javascript If statement used to check file extensions not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836081/javascript-if-statement-used-to-check-file-extensions-not-working)

In JS I'm trying to check whether an extension ends in "png" "jpg" or "gif". I'm aware this can be done with a switch statement, but I'm wondering if there's a simpler way to throw it all in the `if` conditional. Like:

```
    if (aExtensions[i].toLowerCase() == ('jpg' || 'png' || 'gif')) {}
```

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use an array like this:

```
var extensions = ["jpg", "png", "gif"];

if (extensions.indexOf(aExtensions[i].toLowerCase()) > -1) {
    // match
}
```

In this case, you store the "valid" extensions. Then, you can use the `indexOf` method of `Array` to find if any of the items in the array match the specific extension you're looking at - checking for a value that is `0` or greater.

`indexOf` isn't supported on older browsers, so you'd need to include a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill) to back it up. There are several solutions for that.

Of course, if you wanted to only use `if` statements, you could use this format:

```
var ext = aExtensions[i].toLowerCase();
if (ext == "jpg" || ext == "png" || ext == "gif") {
    // match
}
```

Another possibility I can think of is a `switch` statement, like:

```
var ext = aExtensions[i].toLowerCase();

switch (ext) {
    case "jpg":
    case "png":
    case "gif":
        // match
        break;
    case default:
        // No match
}
```

I might as well include it (other answers had it first, definitely), but one more I can think of is using a regex, like:

```
if (/jpg|png|gif/i.test(aExtensions[i])) {
    // match
}
```

But note that you will never be able to individually get the extensions back, and that's why I would prefer one of the first two options I gave.

Answer (score 3):

What about a regex?

```
if ( /jpg|png|gif/i.test( aExtensions[i] ) ) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: +1 - I'd absolutely prefer the regexp in those situations.

Comment: Good answer. Can you explain the purpose of `i` here?

Comment: `i` is _RegExp_'s case insensitive flag

Comment: Interesting. Thanks @PaulS.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way to do this is by using an object literal like this,

```
if ({'jpg':1,'png':1,'gif':1}[aExtensions[i].toLowerCase()]) {
    // ...
}
```

This way you're looking to see if the anonymous object `{'jpg':1,'png':1,'gif':1}` has a property which will be true by the `if`. `1` meets this, `undefined` doesn't.

---

If you're using an object, you could also make use of the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) (as pointed out by [Ian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1317927/ian)) which gives `true` if the object has such a key irrelevant of it's value.

```
if (aExtensions[i].toLowerCase() in {'jpg':0,'png':1,'gif':2}) {
    // ...
}
```

Note this time how `'jpg'` still passes even though `'jpg':0`.

Comment: Can you explain what the `{'jpg':1,'png':1,'gif':1}` does in this instance? Never seen it before in an if statement.

Comment: @Jascination does my edit explain it adequately?

Comment: You could also use `if (aExtensions[i].toLowerCase() in {'jpg':"",'png':"",'gif':""})` in that case

Comment: @Ian Yep, but I'm not sure if `in` works like a loop over the keys (which would be similar to using `indexOf`) or a hashmap.

Comment: @PaulS. I guess it's similar, but it's still very different from `indexOf`. `indexOf` is a value lookup, while `in` is a key lookup. It will have to do the same thing as your original, because we are each providing it a key, and expecting the value back (or in the case of `in` - `true` or `false`). And I did say "you could **also** use" is all

Comment: @Ian, as I say, I'm not sure how `x in obj` works internally compared to `obj[x]`. My doubt that the same method is used for both comes from the fact you can do `for (x in obj)` which suggests to me that `in` involves some kind of iterator. I'm not saying you can't do it this way too though. In fact, I'll edit it into the answer.

Comment: @PaulS:  The [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) [*operator*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.7) is entirely separate from and completely unrelated to the [`for-in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) [*statement*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.4).  The `in` operator simply returns whether or not the named property exists on the object or in the object's prototype chain.

Comment: @josh3736 thanks for clearing that up for me!

Comment: Also, +1 as **this is the most performant way to solve this problem**.  Iterating over an array is slow; object key lookups are *very* fast.

Comment: @josh3736 Yeah, I had a feeling since `in` is used in two different scenarios, they are two different things

Comment: @josh3736 And I wouldn't say iterating over an array is slow - you never actually iterate over an array, you just "count" from a certain integer to the array's length. In a normal `for` loop, accessing the array's item at that index is the consuming part. Using `indexOf` has implications for larger arrays though because it has to go through every key (index) and **then** compare the values. At the same time, both `indexOf` and `in` stop as soon as they find a match at least. Using `in` will only check the key, but `if (x in y)` has to use some internal "loop" we don't see

Comment: @Ian: There's the rub: `in` *doesn't* use a simple internal loop.  JavaScript object property lookup was historically implemented as a relatively fast lookup in a dictionary-like data structure, and in modern engines it is [compiled into a hidden class allowing lookup to be a simple pointer operation](https://developers.google.com/v8/design?hl=fr#prop_access), meaning that lookup is near O(1).  [Compare](http://jsperf.com/array-vs-key-lookup) this to array iteration (comparing the value of each array item), which is a O(n) operation.

Comment: @Ian the last two comments between you and josh3736 were what I wasn't sure of until his comment above linking to the spec.

Comment: @josh3736 (I meant to write this a long time ago) Sorry, I didn't mean to seem like I wasn't in agreement with you. My main point is that `indexOf` is fundamentally different than `key in obj` because `indexOf` isn't a key lookup...it **has** to go through every item (key), get its value, then compare to that value. All `key in obj` has to do is go through every item (key) and compare to that item. Even as a fast lookup, it has to "go through" every item, as does an array in terms of `indexOf`. Both an array and object are stored the same - key/value, we just don't "see" the keys for arrays.

Comment: @Ian "`key in obj` has to do is go through every item (key)", the _"has"_ and _"every"_ here is what the discussion is about. It depends on the implementation and modern implementations actually compile keys as a hidden class, then the `in` operator basically asks _"is there a pointer mapping for this key?"_ or _"is hash(key) defined?"_ without having to _"go though"_ each key.

Comment: @PaulS. Right, I understand. But the point is that to answer "is there a pointer mapping for this key?", something has to analyze whatever implementation of a lookup table there is to determine that...which means "go through" each item in its "lookup table" to see if that key exists. With `indexOf`, it goes an extra step and has to compare the value based on the pointer.

Comment: @Ian: Your understanding of how a key lookup is actually implemented in incorrect.  Yes, `indexOf` (and the `for-in` *statement* `for (var key in obj) { ... }`) must iterate over every key in the object.  However, the `in` *operator* (as used in `if (key in obj) { ... }`) **does not simply iterate over keys** as `indexOf` must.  Lookups are implemented using a very fast mechanism like a [hash lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a variable and triple comparison, but that's ugly.

Or you could just use an array and check if the string is contained in it.

```
if (~ ["jpg", "png", "gif"].indexOf(aExtensions[i].toLowerCase()) …
```

Yet, for the complicated `!= -1` comparison and the lack of native [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) in older IEs, people tend to use regexes:

```
if (/jpg|png|gif/i.test(aExtensions[i])) …
```