# Javascript formatting for if condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check variable equality against a list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728144/check-variable-equality-against-a-list-of-values)
>   [Javascript: Comparing SINGLE Value Against MULTIPLE Values with OR Operands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959064/javascript-comparing-single-value-against-multiple-values-with-or-operands)

First of all I am new to javascript side. Please let me know is there any simple way of formating the below code.

```
if( fileName== 'doc' || fileName=='docx' || fileName=='xls' || fileName=='xlsx' || fileName=='ppt' || fileName=='pdf' ){

Do something

} else{

    Do something

}
```

Comment: I would be keeping an array of possible file extensions, and then checking if the value was in that array.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var SUPPORTED_FILE_EXTENSIONS = ['doc', 'docx', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'ppt', 'pdf'];

if(SUPPORTED_FILE_EXTENSIONS.indexOf(fileName) != -1){
    //Do Something
} else {
    //Do Something Else
}
```

[Array.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) - Note that this also includes information about adding backward compatibility support for older browsers (I.E. IE).

Comment: Tnx @briguy37 :) . It will be nice if you explain this 'FILE_SUPPORTED_EXTENSIONS.indexOf(fileName) != -1'

Comment: Notice that `indexOf` is not supported by old IEs

Comment: SUPPORTED_FILE_EXTENSIONS is the array; .indexOf checks for the occurrence of a string (filename) and returns it's index position unless it's not found then it returns -1.

Comment: @user1817630:  `indexOf` on an array will give you `-1` if the array does not contain the first argument you provide.  Thus, in this case that check will give you a value of `true` when `fileName` is in the supported file extensions.

Answer (score 9):

```
var validTypes = /docx?|xlsx?|ppt|pdf/;

if (fileName.match(validTypes)) {
    ...
}
```

Note: the question mark, `?`, in the Regular Expression indicates the previous character is optional so it can match both `doc` and `docx` the pipe, `|`, indicates `or` so it will match `doc` or `xls`, etc.

Comment: Very nice, never thought to do it using regex. Not as readable as an Array, but I like it! +1

Answer (score 3):

maybe something like

```
var filenames = ['doc','docx','xls','xlsx','ppt','pdf'];
if(filenames.indexOf(fileName) >= 0 ) {
  // Do something
} else {
    // Do something else
}
```

Comment: The most readable way, use this one all the time! +1

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `switch` statement is one of the fastest options:

```
switch (fileName) {
    case "doc":
    case "docx":
    ...
        // ...
    default:
        // else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could reformat it to make the code easier to read:

```
if( fileName == 'doc' || 
    fileName == 'docx' || 
    fileName == 'xls' || 
    fileName == 'xlsx' || 
    fileName == 'ppt' || 
    fileName == 'pdf' ){
    Do something
} else{
    Do something
}
```

Alternatively, you could make the code less repetitive using a construct such as  [`jQuery.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) or [`array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
var arr = ['doc', 'docx', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'ppt', 'pdf'];
if (jQuery.inArray(fileName, arr) > -1){
    Do something
} else{
    Do something
}
```

Comment: why not the native `indexOf`?

Comment: @JosephMarikle - I just added that in. Either is fine, since he is using jQuery (or at least tagged the question as such), so it comes down to personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Creating the array is easier to read. Plus use jQuery's $.inArray() method. It works just like .indexOf() with the added benefit that it's compatible with older version of IE which have a lot of missing array functions.