# short hand for using if statement for single variable over and over again

Tags: c#, if-statement

My question is pretty simple.

Is there a short hand for

```
if (a == "p" || a == "l" || a == "g" || a == "z")
{
            //do something 
}
```

Is there an alternate to this. Meaning, Can I just do something like

`if (a == ("p" || "l" || "g" || "z"))`//this doesn't work

Comment: Similar to all the other questions about this, the answer is: no.

Comment: What language is this?  It looks like C/C++, but one can never be sure with such a small clip.

Comment: I am trying to achieve this in `C#`

Comment: Was asked many times before e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18347033/how-to-shorten-my-conditional-statements - this is JavaScript, but concept is similar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (new[] { "p", "l", "g", "z" }.Contains(a))
```

If performance might be a concern, e.g. you have a large list of strings to check, or check it frequently, you should consider storing them in a [`HashSet<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx), e.g.

```
var mySet = new HashSet<string> { "p", "l", "g", "z" };
// later...
if (mySet.Contains(a))
```

Comment: +1. usual reminder - very readable option for short list, consider `HashSet`/`Dictionary` if list is long/frequently used code.

Answer (score 1):

```
Arrays.asList(new String[]{"a","b","c"}).contains("b");
```

Comment: That looks like Java, this is C# (probably wasn't clear when you wrote that).

Comment: oh, you didn't mention in your post initially, being a Java developer that is what comes to my mind first.

Answer (score 1):

C# code

```
var myList = new[] { "p", "l", "g", "z" };

if(myList.Contains(a))
{
 //victory :)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use switch statement with fall thru:

```
switch (a) {

  case "p":
  case "l":
  case "g":
  case "z":
    // do something
}
```

Comment: My apologies, do use other answers, they're much much shorter

Answer (score 1):

Better if you write an extension method like:

```
public static class MyExtension
{
    public static bool In(this string c, params string[] items)
    {
         return items.Contains(c);
         //OR //return items.Any(r => r == c);
    }
}
```

and then use it like:

```
if ("a".In("p", "l", "a", "z"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exists");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Doesn't exist");
}
```