# How do I say "if value is not equal to a, b, or c"?

Tags: jquery

```
$(this).attr('id') == 'zipcode' && $this.value()!=(3, 4, 5)
```

What I tried to do here was call up the text input field with an id of "zipcode" and say something along the lines of "if value of zipcode is not 3, 4, or 5 then... etc etc..." I tried many combinations including || but nothing has worked. I'll be listing all the possible zip codes and would require the shortest possible way to do it.

Much appreciated.

Full code:

```
function validateStep(step){ if(step == fieldsetCount) return;

var error = 1;
var hasError = false;
$('#formElem').children(':nth-child('+ parseInt(step) +')').find(':input.req:not(button)').each(function(){
    var $this       = $(this);
    var valueLength = jQuery.trim($this.val()).length;
var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/; 

if(valueLength == "" || $(this).attr('id') =='email' && !emailPattern.test($this.val()) || $(this).attr('id') == 'zipcode' && $this.value()!=(3, 4, 5))   

{
        hasError = true;
        $this.css('background-color','#FFEDEF');
    }
    else
        $this.css('background-color','#fff');

});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to shorten my conditional statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18347033/how-to-shorten-my-conditional-statements)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$(this).attr('id') == 'zipcode' && !/^(3|4|5)$/.test($(this).val())
```

Comment: `/^[3-5]$/` would be even shorter here.

Comment: I think so far this is the one I'm able to understand.. Earlier I phrased a keyword wrong in my question. Not 3,4,5 IN zipcode, it should be if zipcode = 3,4 or 5. 

I've tried the other listed answers but some are just beyond my understanding :(. I get what your code is doing but how do I tweek it?...I really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly should it test for? If I've understood your re-wording, then this is already correct. The `^` and `$` cause it to anchor the regexp to the begining and end of the string. That way zipcode must be entirely either '3' or '4' or '5' (rather than just containing those characters).

Comment: It's odd.. 

It's accepting it if the field has more than 2 of the listed value
example: 34a, 44b, a34

Comment: AH!!! Here we go: 

$(this).attr('id') == 'zipcode' && !/^(2|3|4|5)$/.test($(this).val())

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this would be to use `indexOf`:

```
var values = [1,2,3,4];
var value = parseInt($(this).val());
if(values.indexOf(value) == -1) {
    //dostuff
}
```

Comment: Why `parseInt` around the `indexOf` call?

Comment: @user2357112 Sorry, it was supposed to be around the val call.

Comment: Why over complicate things ? `[1, 2, 3].indexOf( parseInt(this.value) ) === -1`

Comment: @Pinocchio That's exactly what's happening in the code anyway. I just moved things to separate statements for clarity because I managed to get the `parseInt` call at the wrong depth because of all the nesting.

Comment: @Pinocchio "`this.value` is nothing like `$(this).val()`" ... Seriously? `val` is a jQuery method for collections that exposes `value` for most input elements and the selected value for select boxes. What's the difference?

Comment: @Pinocchio I wouldn't say *"nothing like"*. jQuery's `val` function does proxy to `elem.value` with some additional magic thrown in. See https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes/val.js#L21

Comment: Thanks  for the help guys. I'm not good with scripting at all so I'm still trying to make sense of all this. Will get back to you guys on what works....

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit shorter:

`$(this).attr('id') == 'zipcode' && $this.value() < 3 && $this.value() > 5`

Comment: this only works if the numbers are 3,4,5. I believe OP was asking for variables

Answer (score 0):

```
//
//  like this
//
function isnoteqto( value /* ...params*/ ) {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ).every( function ( arg ) { return value !== arg; } );
}
//
```

Answer (score 0):

I always like to extend the `String` prototype. Here is an example.

```
String.prototype.isNot = function() {
    for( var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++ ) {
        if( this == arguments[i] ) return false;
    }
    return true;
};
```

Then you can do

```
var value = 'something';

if( value.isNot('value1', 'value2') ) // true
```

And

```
if( value.isNot('something') ) // false
```

If you don't like extending the `String.prototype` you can do this.

```
var isNot = function( value, args ) {
   for( var i = 0; i < args.length; i++ ) {
       if( value == args[i] ) return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

And use like so.

```
var value = 'something';

if( isNot(value, ['value1', 'value2']) ) // true
```

And

```
if( isNot(value, ['something']) ) // false
```

Comment: Extending native types for a tiny bit of syntax sugar is bad ettiquette IMO. edit: just saw your alternative.

Comment: I like the syntactic sugar. for people that don't I have provided another option. I can also think of a lot more **Worse things** to be worrying about.