# How to refactor my conditional statement?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to shorten my code with this conditional statement

I have

```
  if(title =='project'){
      title = text + ': ' + this.projectTitle;
  }else{
      title = this.projectTitle;
  }
```

I feel like there is a better way to rewrite this. Does anyone have idea of how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: That looks pretty short already. Why try to shorten it? *Edit:* And the three current answers demonstrate starkly that you’re not going to end up with something more readable than the original.

Comment: So, I'm *fascinated* by the serial, unexplained, down-voting...

Comment: @DavidThomas I downvoted because the OP is trying to shorten a piece of code that is already trivially short. (And while this may not be fair, I think people expect more “research effort” and a more useful question from a user with 3k reputation.)

Comment: have to agree with @bdesham, SO isn't a place to go and learn what a ternary operator is; that would be a tutor, book or website

Comment: While I'm @DavidThomas, fascinated by the serial, unexplained, [up-voting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18347033/how-to-shorten-my-conditional-statements).

Comment: I understand the question is very bad. It was a bad post and I apologize. Thanks all

Comment: Down-voting, though, implies that the answer is 'not useful,' which I realise is a subjective determination (though to my mind should be 'does not answer, or address, the question'); none of the posted answers failed to address, or solve, the question as asked. So it feels like those that answered are being punished simply because someone found the *question* lacked merit. Obviously down-votes are given at the whims of individual users (and I have no problem *being* down-voted, but I'd like some explanation as to *why* I'm being down-voted, so thanks for that at least).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ternary that reproduces your `if`/`else`:

```
title = title == 'project' ? text + ': ' + this.projectTitle : this.projectTitle;
```

Though if you really want to shorten it:

```
title = (title == 'project' ? text + ': ' : '') + this.projectTitle;
```

References:

- [Conditional ('ternary') operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Answer (score 1):

Try a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
title = (title =='project') ? text + ': ' + this.projectTitle: this.projectTitle;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple inline condition;

```
   title =  ((title =='project') ? text + ': ' + this.projectTitle : this.projectTitle);
```

Check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270351/how-to-write-an-inline-if-statement-in-javascript) for more details

Answer (score 1):

```
title = (title == 'project' ? text + ': ' : '') + this.projectTitle;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var title = (title =='project' ? text + ': ' + this.projectTitle : this.projectTitle);
```