# Or condition never evaluates to true

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

this javascript code runs successfully but I think it doesn't make through its "else" statement since it doesn't print its console...why?

```
 i = 0;
    for(var i=1; i<4; i++) {
    var crazy = prompt("would you marry me?");
         if(crazy === "Yes"|| "yes") {
           console.log("hell ya!");
       }
     /* when it asks "will you marry me" and if the user says either "No" or      "no", it does't print "ok..I'' try again next time". instead, it still says "hell ya !" */
     else if (crazy ==="No" ||"no") {
       console.log("ok..I'll try again next time !");
   }
}
var love = false;
do {
      console.log("nonetheless, I LOVE YOU !");
}
while(love);
```

Comment: The syntax for the conditions isn't correct. You need to check the variable again. `crazy === 'Yes' || crazy === 'yes'`

Comment: It should be `crazy === "Yes" || crazy === "yes"`. `||'yes'` is not _compared_ but evaluated as `true`.

Comment: It is my pleasure I can help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript if statement with multiple permissible conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944216/javascript-if-statement-with-multiple-permissible-conditions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..Nice piece of code though.. Is it a marriage proposal to some geeky guy?

```
i = 0;
    for(var i=1; i<4; i++) {
    var crazy = prompt("would you marry me?");
         if(crazy === "Yes"|| crazy ==="yes") {
           console.log("hell ya!");
       }
     /* when it asks "will you marry me" and if the user says either "No" or      "no", it does't print "ok..I'' try again next time". instead, it still says "hell ya !" */
     else if (crazy ==="No" ||crazy === "no") {
       console.log("ok..I'll try again next time !");
   }
}
var love = false;
do {
      console.log("nonetheless, I LOVE YOU !");
}
while(love);
```

Comment: hey thank you so much ! This is a lot of help..haha:)) No I don't have boyfriend but I thought maybe this can help some guys someday to make it less stressful and actually funny just by telling their girlfriend to enter their website and then Wow !

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this,

```
 if(crazy.toUpperCase() === "YES") {
    console.log("hell ya!");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here’s the explanation:

```
crazy === "Yes" || "yes"
```

This statement does the following thing:

1. It compares whether `crazy` is identical to the string `"Yes"`
2. If they’re not identical, “use” `"yes"`

Put this into an `if` statement and you get this:

- Execute everything in `if` block,

  1. …if `crazy` is identical to `"Yes"`, ***or***
  2. …if *`"yes"`*.

What does *`"yes"`* by itself mean in an `if` statement? It is evaluated as **`true`**.

Every string that is not the empty string is evaluated as `true` and every empty string is evaluated as `false`. See the MDN articles on [`Boolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) and [falsy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

You can verify this by typing doubly-negated expressions like these into the console:

```
!!"yes"; // true
!!"test"; // true
!!""; // false
```

What you need to do is a second comparison:

```
if(crazy === "Yes" || crazy === "yes")
```

and

```
else if(crazy === "No" || crazy === "no")
```

Alternative approaches include `crazy.toLowerCase() === "yes"` for only one comparison, or `["Yes", "yes"].includes(crazy)`.