# If statement with (a == b && c == d || e) || a != b)

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm trying to get a value in a dropdown to not show if another value is selected. 
Basically saying if Internal is showing, don't show Record_type_wf or record_type_vr
But when adding in the or statement for VR it just breaks and they both always show up.

```
if((zoneLocation == 'internal' && optionObj[option].value != 'record_type_wf' || 'vanity_type_vr') || zoneLocation != 'internal'){
    g_form.addOption('dns_record_type', optionObj[option].value, optionObj[option].text, optionObj[option].order);

    if (optionObj[option].value == currentRecordType){
        keepCurrentOption = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: To those voting to close as a typo: This is not a typo, it's a misunderstanding about what JavaScript's logical operators do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Simple way to check if variable is equal to two or more values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116326/javascript-simple-way-to-check-if-variable-is-equal-to-two-or-more-values)

Comment: Also relevant [JavaScript OR (||) variable assignment explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100758/javascript-or-variable-assignment-explanation)

Comment: [Javascript: The prettiest way to compare one value against multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121395/javascript-the-prettiest-way-to-compare-one-value-against-multiple-values)

Comment: [Javascript if statement with multiple permissible conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944216/javascript-if-statement-with-multiple-permissible-conditions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not mean what you think it means:

```
(zoneLocation == 'internal' && optionObj[option].value != 'record_type_wf' || 'vanity_type_vr')
```

Note that `'vanity_type_vr'` is a truthy value, and so this test *always succeeds*, because it's interpreted like this:

```
(zoneLocation == 'internal') && (optionObj[option].value != 'record_type_wf') || ('vanity_type_vr')
```

This entire expression (converted to boolean) simplifies to `true` because of the last operand.

This is what you meant:

```
(zoneLocation == 'internal' && optionObj[option].value != 'record_type_wf' && optionObj[option].value != 'vanity_type_vr')
```