# Why my condition is always true

Tags: javascript, lodash

I would like to know in this example why my condition is always true ? Thanks

```
function bla() {
  var qix = 'z'
  if (qix === 'a' || 'b' || 'c') {
     console.log('condition ok!! whats wrong???')
  }
}
```

Comment: There are two `"c"` in your condition.

Comment: You've misunderstood how the `||` operator works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use OR condition in a JavaScript IF statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363840/how-to-use-or-condition-in-a-javascript-if-statement)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: The prettiest way to compare one value against multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121395/javascript-the-prettiest-way-to-compare-one-value-against-multiple-values). Voted to close as that, but I actually meant [Javascript If statement used to check file extensions not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11836081/4642212). Oh well.

Comment: I think there is no need of a strict comparison here. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript)

Comment: @TakitIsy It’s considered good practice to always use `===`, and `==` only when applicable.

Comment: @Xufox, and so, when is `==` applicable ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the `if` expression always evaluates to `true`.

```
qix === 'a' || 'b' || 'c'
```

will actually become this:

```
false || 'b' || 'c'
```

as `qix` is set to `z`. Due to loose typing, JavaScript returns `true` for the second expression because 'b' is a [truthy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy). To correct that, you need to change the expression as follows:

```
qix === 'a' || qix === 'b' || qix === 'c'
```

so that it correctly means what you're expecting.

Answer (score 4):

Description of `expr1 || expr2` from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators):

> Returns expr1 if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, || returns true if either operand is true.

```
o1 = true  || true       // t || t returns true
o2 = false || true       // f || t returns true
o3 = true  || false      // t || f returns true
o4 = false || (3 == 4)   // f || f returns false
o5 = 'Cat' || 'Dog'      // t || t returns "Cat"
o6 = false || 'Cat'      // f || t returns "Cat"
o7 = 'Cat' || false      // t || f returns "Cat"
o8 = ''    || false      // f || f returns false
o9 = false || ''         // f || f returns ""
```

So this expression from your code, assuming qix is not `'a'`:

```
qix === 'a' || 'b' || 'c'
```

The first term `qux === 'a'` is `false`, which of course evaluates to false. This causes it to go to the next term which is `'b'`. Non-empty strings evaluate to `true`, so it stops there and just becomes `'b'`. Now your if statement can be thought of as just:

```
if ('b')
```

Again, `'b'` evaluates to `true`. So your conditional is effectively doing nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing two concepts.

First how the || operator works and second coercion of javascript values.

In your code:

```
  if ('z' === 'a' || 'b' || 'c') { ----}
```

Will always evaluate to `true`.
The reason for this is that the || operator will give back the first value which coerces to true without actually coercing the value. The associativity (order which the operators are executed) is left-to-right. This means that the following happens:

First the following will be evaluated because it has higher [precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence):

```
'z' === 'a' // false
```

then we have the following expression which will be evaluated left to right:

```
false || 'b' || 'c'
```

```js
let foo = false || 'b'

console.log(foo)
```

Then we have the following expression:

```js
let foo = 'b' || 'c'

console.log(foo)
```

So the whole expression evulates to the string `'b'`

**After** the expression inside the if statement is evaluated to the value 'b' this in turn then gets coerced into a boolean. Every string gets converted to `true` and that's why the value is always true.

Answer (score 1):

As we know `||` (`OR` Logical Operators) returns `true` if either operand is true. In your if condition `qix === 'a' || 'b' || 'c'` in their second and third operand is string and Strings are considered `false` if and only if they are empty otherwise true. For this reason, your condition is always true.

Need to check qix like qix ==='b'

```js
 var qix = 'z'
  if (qix === 'a' || qix === 'b' || qix ==='c') {
     console.log('condition ok!! whats wrong???')
  }
  else{
      console.log('else')
  }
```

Comment: Because this is an obvious duplicate question.

Comment: @Xufox Thanks for finding out my mistake. I have changed my answerer.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you 'if condition' is take 3 possible option

First say qix === 'a', this is false but you asking about 'b','c' and this option are values true because you are not compare var qix with 'b' or 'c', you only asking to IF condition, that if 'b' or 'c' are value

the operator || it is used so

```
if(First Condition || Second Condition || third condition){
 if at least one of these options is true, then enter here
}
```

In **ECMAScript 2016** incorporates an includes() method for arrays that specifically solves the answer

```
if (['b', 'c', 'a'].includes(qix)) {
    this is false
}

if (['z', 'c', 'a'].includes(qix)) {
    this is true
}
```

Or you can write so

```
function bla() {
  var qix = 'z'
  if (qix === 'a' || qix === 'b' || qix === 'c') {
     console.log('condition ok!! whats wrong???')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript returns true for the second or expression because 'b' is always true.

You need to check each value against qix like so:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators

```js
  var qix = 'z'
  if (qix === 'a' || qix === 'b' ||  qix === 'c') {
     console.log('condition ok!! whats wrong???')
  }
```

Comment: Because this is an obvious duplicate question.

Comment: Applicable to currently two answers here: downvoted, because “try this instead” or “you need to use this” are _not_ answers to a “why” question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Regex: `qix.match(/^(a|b|c)$/)`
Should return if `qix` is equals to `a` or `b` or `c`

```js
var qix = 'z';
if (qix.match(/^(a|b|c)$/)) {
   console.log('condition ok!! whats wrong???');
} else {
   console.log('else');
}
```